# "I'd better" or "it would be better"?

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, subjunctives, contractions

I wrote the following question in another StackExchange website:

> If I want to save and retrieve an object, should I create another class to handle it, or **it would be better** to do that in the class itself?

Is it better to say it as:

> If I want to save and retrieve an object, should I create another class to handle it, or **I'd** better to do that within the class itself?

I thought the second is better because it is in accord with the first sentence of the OR conjunction (both begin with "I").

In general, are they equivalent? I mean "it would be better.." and "I'd better..."? Which is more common?

Comment: @choster -- This quote looks like a question posted on a professional-level programming Q&A board (such as a StackExchange site).  It could even be a topic question in a book on programming, written in a semi-formal Q&A style.

Comment: Depending on your audience you could even get away with an elided form "or better to do that...?"

Comment: @choster As I modified the question, its a question in a Q&A website

Answer (score 15):

**Both are not quite right.**

"It would be better" is how you would phrase a declarative sentence - a statement of fact. To ask a question, start with the question word ("Would it be better...?"). This makes the whole question of the contraction unnecessary :)

But if you still want to know a bit about "it would" read on:

1) The correct contraction for "it would" is "it'd". I'd means "I would", or "I had", depending on the context. For example, "I'd better..." Would be "I had better...", meaning that I should do something. "I'd like..." means "I would like..."

2) "It'd" is not very common in written English (although it is common in spoken English). As a general rule, I would use "it would" 99% of the time.

Comment: Seconding the "would it be better" suggestion.

"If I want to save and retrieve an object, should I create another class to handle it, or would it be better to do that in the class itself?"

Comment: Thank you, yes, I mistook in making the question, but that wasn't my question. I asked about which is more appropriate there. or their difference, "I'd better" and "It would be better".

Comment: Note: you made the same mistake of "I'd better" rather than "It'd [be] better". I'd != it'd.

But yes, "it would be better" is the appropriate option of those 2, not "it'd/I'd be better". (but "would it be better?" is how you to ask a question.)

Answer (score 8):

We use “had better” plus the infinitive without “to”  to give advice. Although “had” is the past form of “have”, we use “had better” to give advice about the present or future.

You'd better tell her everything.
I'd better get back to work.

Comment: It's worth to mention that its negative form is *had better not* and not *had not better.*

Comment: Then you mean in my question, I'd better use "would it better"?

Answer (score 4):

Your two sentences would make more sense if they were:

> If I want to save and retrieve an object, should I create another class to handle it, or **would it be better** to do that in the class itself?

You started a question, so your phrases should all be questions (as mentioned by Sarah).  When you are using "it" in "would it be better", you are talking about the situation you will be in if you follow that path.

Or:

> If I want to save and retrieve an object, should I create another class to handle it, or **would I be better off** doing that within the class itself?

Changing the code won't improve you as a person, no matter what your boss might say!  That means that "I'd be better" isn't true.
As in your first sentence, your situation might improve, so you might be "better off".  Note that "would" still comes first, because you are still asking a question.

"I'd better" is short for "I had better" so:

> If I want to save and retrieve an object, **should I** create another class or **had I better** do that in the class itself?

This is a less common way of asking for a comparison of two options, however.

It is probably simpler (and easier to understand) if you ask the question using the same type of phrase in both halves:

> If I want to save and retrieve an object, **should I** create another class to handle it, or **should I** do that within the class itself?
>
> If I want to save and retrieve an object, **would it be better** to create another class to handle it, **or** do that in the class itself?

Comment: Thank you very much! you pointed "would I be better" and "I'd be better", what about "I'd better"? how to make question with it? and is it equivalent to "I'd be better"?

Comment: Edited to include your answer, but the difference is around "I'd better" being "I had better" and "I'd be better" is "I would be better".  All options require you to put the question word at the front of the phrase anyway.